# Unable to obtain access token using Office.auth.getAccessToken in Office Add-in

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use the method to obtain an access token in my Office Add-in. Here is the code snippet I am using:Office.auth.getAccessToken

```
Office.auth.getAccessToken({
    allowSignInPrompt: true,
    allowConsentPrompt: true,
    forMSGraphAccess: true,
}).then(res => {
    console.log(res);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log("Error obtaining token", err);
});
```

However, when running the code, I encounter the following error:

```
{
    "name": "Invalid application resource URL.",
    "message": "The resource URL specified in the manifest is invalid.",
    "code": 13004
}
```

This error indicates that the provided application resource URL is invalid. Here is the relevant section from my manifest file:

```
<WebApplicationInfo>
    <Id>$app-id-guid$</Id>
    <Resource>api://localhost:300/login/$app-id-guid$</Resource>
    <Scopes>
        <Scope>Files.Read</Scope>
        <Scope>profile</Scope>
        <Scope>openid</Scope>
    </Scopes>
</WebApplicationInfo>
```

I'm not clear on what the address represents and how to modify it for authorization login through my own website. Can you please provide guidance on how to modify the URL for authorization login using my website?ResourceResource

Any help in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

**Issue:**
Encountered an "Invalid application resource URL" error when using `Office.auth.getAccessToken` in an Office Add-in.

**Solution:**

1. **Azure AD App Registration:**

   - Go to the [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com/).
   - Navigate to "Azure Active Directory" > "App registrations."
   - Find your app by the ID specified in the manifest.
   - Update the "Redirect URI" to point to your website's authentication endpoint.
2. **Manifest:**

   - Modify the resource URL in your manifest to match the "App ID URI" from your Azure AD App registration (`api://app-id-guid`).

   ```xml
   <WebApplicationInfo>
       <Id>$app-id-guid$</Id>
       <Resource>api://app-id-guid</Resource>
       <Scopes>
           <Scope>Files.Read</Scope>
           <Scope>profile</Scope>
           <Scope>openid</Scope>
       </Scopes>
   </WebApplicationInfo>
   ```

Replace $app-id-guid$ with your App ID GUID.

Remember to handle the authentication flow on your website, and the redirect URI should point to a valid endpoint on your server to receive the authentication response.

After making these changes, run your Office Add-in again to check if the issue is resolved.

Comment: "Hello, thank you very much for getting back to my question.
I have registered the application, and in the manifest, I have also filled in the ID and Resource address. I am a little confused about one thing, should the application ID URI be the request address of the API I built myself, or the address of the Office add-in application?"